# How to implement a fragment inside a fragment (getting Android.Support.V4.App or Android.App conversion errors) In Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am implementing a fragment inside a fragment in my project but unable to do that i am getting this errors while implementing it.
[image: When i use this same code a new sample project i am able to create and bind a fragment in to another fragment successfully, where as i am unable to do the same while implementing in real project]

When i use this same code a new sample project i am able to create and bind a fragment in to another fragment successfully, where as i am unable to do the same while implementing in real project
[image: Also tried doing this which did not help me]

I also tried using getActivity(),Activity(), and all resources available online but unable to do that

Can anyone please solve this problem which i am facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just refine your code by using this:

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = new FragmentForSliderView();
Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.AddSlider, fragment).Commit();
```

Comment: Hello...
this is giving me the similar problem as you can see in the last photo.
that too SupportFragmentManager is not supporting me to use.
the suggested changes shown when i am pressing Ctrl+. is as follows
generate:- Property, field, read only field, local, class, nested class.

Comment: I have updated the code, try out this. It's casting problem.

Comment: Make sure your fragment is inherited from Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment